# Does Spyder download its own Python with it?

Tags: python, windows, pip, spyder

Common issue here: I installed Python and then Spyder, and now when I install packages with "pip install ", Spyder can't find the modules, but if I call Python on the command prompt (using Windows), it finds all installed packages with pip.

I noticed that in Spyder, a new console shows it is running Python 3.7.9, but if I run "python -V" on the command promp, it shows Python 3.9.1 , also for "py -0" and "py -0p" it only shows one installation of Python, namely

```
>>> py -0p
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows                                                                       
-3.9-64        C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe *
```

so what is going on here? Why does Spyder seem to have its own Python version? Is this the reason why packages installed with pip are not communicating with Spyder?

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue as you. I understand your question and the answer to it is yes. However you can change it and use the systems python as well.

Tools -> preferences -> python interpreter -> select "use the following interpreter" and provide is the path to the directory that you have the systems python installed.

Restart spyder and the kernel should then show you the update version

Comment: This worked for me.  When I downloaded Spyder 5.2.2 the default python was 3.7.9 and some of the modules weren't loading properly.  After changing the python interpreter to the most up-to-date version, I was off to the races.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For any library that you want to add that is not included in the default search path of spyder, you need add its path via the PYTHONPATH manager.

```
Go to Spyder->Tool-> PYTHONPATH manager ->Add Path
```

Comment: That would be a workaround but it doesn't solve the problem that Spyder is inherently disconnected of pip, and also using a different Python version...  Either way, I added the path and problem still persists

Comment: You can change the python version in spyder by going to the preference tab in spyder. Pip is a package manager and spyder is ide..The reason the packages are not communicating is that the ide can not find them. That's why i suggested to include them in your path

Comment: So what I am understanding is that, yes, Spyder downloads its own Python (in my case Python 3.7.9, ignoring the system's Python 3.9.1), and when I run pip, that pip obeys the system's python (3.9.1) and Spyder can't interact with it, unless I change the python version whithin Spyder, which by the way throws the following error "Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 1.10.0 and < 1.11.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you."   What a mess!

Comment: So i guess, for any future Spyder user, the recommendation would be to NOT install Python independently. Just install Spyder, which will come with its own Python. Why is this not mentioned anywhere on the Spyder website?

Comment: I use spyder within anaconda. I would recommend you to create virtual environment in anaconda for different versions of python and use spyder within that virtual environment without any issues. It is cleaner this way. You can install all the packages within that virtual environment without messing with the versions each time

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to Sarim's answer that -- usually -- the path is something like the following (Windows):

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
```

Where instead of "UserName" you should insert your user name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, I would recommend in future to click on the Edit link under the relevant answer to suggest an edit, that makes it easier to find the relevant information, but for now I've edited your post also, do demonstrate how to format answers better too. Have a nice day!