Biopython import of packages leads to circular import error
I am trying to run the following simple biopython code
from Bio import SeqIO
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("ls_orchid.fasta", "fasta"):
    print(seq_record.id)
    print(repr(seq_record.seq))
    print(len(seq_record))

However, I keep getting this error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'pairwisealigner' from partially
initialized module 'Bio.Align' (most likely due to a circular import)
(C:\Users\conno\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\Bio\Align_init.py)

Looking at the file of what I am importing, it says:
# Import errors may occur here if a compiled _pairwisealigner.c file or
# compiled _codonaligner.c file (_pairwisealigner.pyd or _pairwisealigner.so,
# or _codonaligner.pyd or _codonaligner.so) is missing or if the user is
# importing from within the Biopython source tree, see PR #2007:
# https://github.com/biopython/biopython/pull/2007

I literally have no idea what this means so have no idea how to fix it.

How did you install biopython?

I really struggled trying to install it, because I use Spyder, so I ended up downloading through both pip install and miniconda3, but I think the pip install one is the one that I'm running.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65671238/does-spyder-download-its-own-python-with-it  Does Spyder download its own Python with it?
